# A JNI error has occurred, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, java-native-interface, manifest

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\BCJ_DEC_2016\workspace\CoreJava\creditcardprocess\target>java -jar creditcardprocess-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more

C:\BCJ_DEC_2016\workspace\CoreJava\creditcardprocess\target>




**MANIFEST.MF**

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: Bootcamp User 005
Class-Path: lib/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar lib/commons-logging-1.2.
 jar lib/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE
 .jar lib/spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-4.3.7.R
 ELEASE.jar lib/mail-1.5.0-b01.jar lib/activation-1.1.1.jar lib/spring
 -tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar lib/hibernate-core-4.3.3.Final.jar lib/jboss-lo
 gging-3.1.3.GA.jar lib/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar lib/
 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar li
 b/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.j
 ar lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.
 jar lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar lib/mysql-connecto
 r-java-6.0.6.jar lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar 
 lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar 
 lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar lib/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-j
 dbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Main-Class: com.bcj.creditcardprocess.CreditCardMain

**POM.XML**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bcj</groupId>
    <artifactId>creditcardprocess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>creditcardprocess</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.bcj.creditcardprocess.CreditCardMain</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>

  </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In my MANIFEST.MF file it shows the spring-context dependency but it is again throwing an exception saying ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext. but it runs well in eclipse. Why this happens?

Comment: Maybe you have to bundle the dependencies in the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `maven-assembly-plugin` instead of `maven-jar-plugin`, as it doesn't include dependencies into JAR-file.